# Compiling / installing up-to-date nginx with fastcgi_cache on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

What is the recommended path to compile or install `nginx` with `fastcgi_cache` on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` `precise` that works with up-to-date nginx-common (***read >= ver 1.2.7***) packages?

Or is there a method to efficiently compile nginx completely from scratch in a debian / ubuntu server that is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an "official" recommended path. What i usually like to do is the following:

`configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx-1.2.7` or whatever the version number is

`ln -s /usr/local/nginx-1.2.7 /usr/local/nginx` To link to the currently active version

Then i always start it using the path without version `/usr/local/nginx` and write the init scripts accordingly. This makes updating it much easier by first installing the newer version into another path and later just changing the link:

`configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx-1.2.8`

`ln -fs /usr/local/nginx-1.2.8 /usr/local/nginx` change the link and then restart

Furthermore it makes it easy to switch back if you discover that there is a problem with the newer version.

For temporary things like the cache, if memory allows, i create a `tmpfs` partition and mount it in something like `/var/nginx`.